# Чтение файла с ошибкой nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

У меня в express.js есть `router.get` в котором я делаю exec другого скрипта, который пишет в определенное место новый файл. Как аргумент я передаю в другой скрипт `var flName = uniqid();`, который послужит именем нового файла.
И тут же в рамках этого `роутер.гет` нужно прочитать созданный файл. Для этого я использую такую конструкцию:

```
function readJson(flName) {
    fs.readFileSync('public/result/' + flName + '.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    });
}


var rj = readJson(flName);
```

**Суть проблемы**: результатом исполнения я получаю не **false**, а `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/result/%Значение переменной flName%.json'`. Как получать `false`?

В целом идея вызывать `var rj = readJson(flName);` в цикле с помощью `setInterval` пока вместо `false` не придет `data`. Возможно есть более оптимальный подход?

**UPD:**

```
function toObject() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}
```

...

```
var flName = uniqid();
    var list = toObject(flName, JSON.stringify(req.query));


    var program = exec('phantomjs ./phantom/folder/search.js', list, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        //действия после записи файла
        var rdj = readJson(flName);
        console.log('RESULT: ');
        console.log(rdj);
    });
```

Возникает та же проблема, но уже не отображается к ответе сервера, а тормозит сервак и пишется в консоль:

> fs.js:653   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
>   stringToFlags(flags), mode);
>                    ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'public/result/hphyujnfloj8ujj17b.json'

Comment: Зачем так сложно все. Почему файл не писать прямо по месту?

Comment: что Вы имеете ввиду? у меня сложность в том, что это в любом случае должно быть два разных файла. Один экспресс.джс получает запрос, второй на фантомджс исполняет запрос с указанными параметрами и пишет результат в файл. а теперь экспрессджс как-то должен этот файл прочесть, но не раньше чем он будет записан.

Comment: У readFileSync нет коллбека

Comment: @AlexeyTen а что посоветуете использовать в моей ситуации?

Comment: Вам уже посоветовали дождаться выполнения exec

Comment: там есть сложность своя, обновил вопрос

Comment: @J. Doe хорошо. Выполнение доходит до **var rdj = readJson(flName);** и на этой функции валится. Я правильно понял? Если да, то на диске файл действительно существует? И как заметил Alexey Ten у readFileSync нет параметра callback. Такой параметр есть у асинхронной fs.readFile

Comment: А ваш фантом точно файл пишет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете для запуска другого процесса exec, то можете передавать в вызов аргументом функцию, которая будет вызываться, когда процесс завершится. Дополнительно потребуется обеспечить условие, по которому при завершении другого процесса файл должен быть уже записан. Тогда все действия по чтению файла вам потребуется выполнять в этой функции. Выглядить это может примерно так:

```
exec('script.js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
 //действия после записи файла
 readJson(flName);
}
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос, проблема не исчезла. Спасибо.